# Does a Catoblepas statblock appear in an official D&D 5e product?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

The catoblepas appeared in various monster manuals throughout D&D's editions. Have WotC published stats for it in a D&D 5th edition product yet? If so, which?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

## Yes.

The catoblepas was published in *Volo's Guide to Monsters* (page 129) for 5e. It is available [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/catoblepas) on D&D Beyond behind a paywall that requires purchasing the content.

Note that you can also use D&D Beyond to [search monsters](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters) that are available in official D&D publications. You will be able to see the search results including the monster's name, type, CR, and publication source even if the full stat block is behind a paywall. (For example, [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-search=catoblepas) are the search results for "catoblepas.")

Comment: +1 for not only giving an answer, but also providing a solution for how to obtain the information for similar questions.